# Standard approach for syncing files via server in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm working on a notepad application, and I'm looking for a way to have it sync file's to a server. The first ideas I have are ftp, which seems like a clunky approach to me (although it does seem fairly simple) or an sql database.

Is there a better approach to doing this? I know syncing to a server is fairly common, so I'm thinking I must be missing a better approach, since neither of these seem optimal.

Comment: well, you need to be more specific about it. what exactly do you need? do you need interoperability or will you implement your own protocol for the sync? how big will the data be? any chances of syncing something other than text?

Comment: Sorry about that.

I need to sync a text file with a server, size could range, its a notepad, but very little space is wasted, so size comes down to how much is typed, expect small sizes, only example I have so far is 4kb, and that's a decently sized notebook. As far as interoperability goes, I can work with pretty much anything, I have control of the server and the program, and this isn't a large scale program, so the protocol isn't too important, it just needs to work.

Comment: if i were you then, i'd just create a server which exposes some WCF services that enables you to sync (download/upload text data, login with your username password etc.), and at the server side, store them to a database. if it's not a very big performance critical project you may also consider using the Entity Framework, which will do most of the "ugly" work for you.

Comment: @can: If i were you i'd turn that comment into an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i were you, i'd just create a server which exposes some WCF services that enables you to sync (download/upload text data, login with your username password etc.), and at the server side, store them to a database. if it's not a very big performance critical project you may also consider using the Entity Framework, which will do most of the "ugly" work for you.

Comment: Another good part about this solution is that you can write a method to sync just a part of a file, rather than having to send the entire file every time.

Comment: yes (i didn't think of it honestly :)) but as most files are very small in size, we don't even need it.